# Do projects get compiled with dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm sorry if this has been asked elsewhere - but my guess is that it hasn't since it should be a "duh" question. I have a solution with 5 projects. Since there is no such option as "Build Solution Deployment Package", do the project dependencies also get compiled/built in the deployment package?

ie. If i have a project called "API-REST" which depends on another project "DbContext", will DbContext get built into API-REST or will I need to somehow build them separately? Developing seems to have been easier than the deploying to server part.

/confused - sorry for my idiocy.

Comment: Just o be clear, you are asking if all the projects will be built or if he dependencies will be somehow included in your deployment package?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the projects are in the same solution VS will compile all projects when the "startup project" is built. You will be able to find the dll files under this projects bin/debug folder.

So when you publish or send to an install project all the dlls in that folder will also be included (although reference dlls will not by default), if you are looking for then after the project quick publish they will be under the "application files" folder and have the additional deploy extension.